# acces denied. static IP. netplan. ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, netplan

I have an old computer, and I decided to make a server out of it, install Ubuntu 19.04 server on it, and everything was fine until I tried to configure a static interface. I ordered it from the provider. Everything went well, but when I insert it into netplan, when I log in via ssh (I use PuTTY and WinSCP), access is denied. Port 2323 is configured in sshd_config, and when netplan is the default setting, it works, but when there is a static ip, I still need port 22 to connect.

```
network:
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s7:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [193.186.9.39/24]
            gateway4: 193.186.9.1
            nameservers:
                     addresses: [193.186.9.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Ufw info:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

[image]

Connection on port 22, 193.186.9.39 (static):

[image]

Connection on port 2323 :
*Network Error: Connection timed out*

[image]

I tried to give access from the Internet to my sites and programs, but so far I have encountered such a problem.
In Ubuntu, I recently. I beg you to help, I have been suffering for 3 days. Thank you very much.

---

up.

sudo netstat -tnlp | grep ssh
[image]

ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
[image]

Everything is fine when the netplan

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp0s7:
            dhcp4: true
```

---

sshd_config

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 2323
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 1m
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers aborigen
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: What's the output of `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep ssh`? Does the machine have internet connectivity? Can you include `sshd_config` in your question?

Comment: Does internet work on the machine? What happens if you run `ping www.google.com`?

Comment: i include images

Comment: Please don't use images for text. But the problem is that you don't have a working internet connection. Are you sure that the settings is correct? What happens if you try `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8 response: destination host unreachable

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a working internet connection. Check with whoever provides you internet how you should configure your host to get a working connection.

Comment: Thank you, you sent me in the right direction. I have not configured port forwarding on the router :)

Comment: You have a public IP on the computer according to what you write. If this is at home, that's very unlikely, and you should probably change to private IP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up port forwarding on the router solved my problem. No need to touch anything in the netplan.